# Mule reuse request-reply (same JMS Queues)

Tags: mule, esb

My flow is necessary to use the component request-reply twice, but when I try to do the following problem:

```
    <flow name="myprojectFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <request-reply doc:name="RR1">
            <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="req_queue" doc:name="JMS" connector-ref="Active_MQ">
                <jms:transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN"/>
            </jms:outbound-endpoint>
            <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="rep_queue" doc:name="JMS" connector-ref="Active_MQ">
                <jms:transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN"/>
            </jms:inbound-endpoint>
        </request-reply>
        <request-reply doc:name="RR2">
            <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="req_queue" doc:name="JMS" connector-ref="Active_MQ">
                <jms:transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN"/>
            </jms:outbound-endpoint>
            <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="rep_queue" doc:name="JMS" connector-ref="Active_MQ">
                <jms:transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN"/>
            </jms:inbound-endpoint>
        </request-reply>
    </flow>
```

Another system receives a message from req_queue and send into rep_queue.

Error:

```
ERROR 2015-10-07 19:48:41,703 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: null
org.mule.api.transport.ConnectorException: There is already a listener registered on this connector on endpointUri: jms://rep_queue. Connector that caused exception is: ActiveMQJmsConnector
{
  name=Active_MQ
  lifecycle=start
  this=75361cf6
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
  connected=true
  supportedProtocols=[jms]
  serviceOverrides=<none>
}

    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector.registerListener(AbstractConnector.java:1258) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.endpoint.DefaultInboundEndpoint.start(DefaultInboundEndpoint.java:104) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.routing.requestreply.SimpleAsyncRequestReplyRequester.start(SimpleAsyncRequestReplyRequester.java:87) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.start(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:102) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct.startIfStartable(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:325) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractPipeline.doStart(AbstractPipeline.java:351) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.construct.Flow.doStart(Flow.java:90) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct$2.onTransition(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:136) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
```

How can I use the request-reply with the same JMS queue twice in one flow?

Answer (score 0):

Are your sure about JMS queues your pointing? I can see your sending message to "req_queue" and pointing to the "rep_queue" to receive message. you will never get the message there from "rep_queue". I have modified slightly and worked from me. let me know if it's not fulfill your requirement...

```
<flow name="myprojectFlow">
<http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration1" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
<set-payload doc:name="Set Payload" value="Hi"/>
<request-reply doc:name="RR1">
    <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="req_queue" doc:name="JMS" connector-ref="Active_MQ">
        <jms:transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN"/>
    </jms:outbound-endpoint>
    <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="req_queue" doc:name="JMS" connector-ref="Active_MQ">
        <jms:transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN"/>
    </jms:inbound-endpoint>
</request-reply>
<logger message="---- payload ---#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
<request-reply doc:name="RR2">
    <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="req_queue1" doc:name="JMS" connector-ref="Active_MQ">
        <jms:transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN"/>
    </jms:outbound-endpoint>
    <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="req_queue1" doc:name="JMS" connector-ref="Active_MQ">
        <jms:transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN"/>
    </jms:inbound-endpoint>
</request-reply>
<logger message="---- payload1 ---#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer
But, I think you made a mistake
Another system receives a message from req_queue and send into rep_queue. The question is how to use twice the same rep_queue for successive request-reply.

Comment: why do you want two listeners for the same "rep_queue"? As per my knowledge you can't register multiple listeners on same queue in single session. you need to have different session to register multiple listeners.Or you can use topic insted of queue. See the activemq documentation http://activemq.apache.org/multiple-consumers-on-a-queue.html

Comment: I try to use topics, but it is not work - same error:

ConnectorException: There is already a listener registered on this connector on endpointUri: jms://topic:TestTopic. Connector that caused exception is: ActiveMQJmsConnector

"Another system" - it's another mule flow. It does not have outbound element and automatically send reply message to request-reply element of mainFlow.
How to make reply-JMS (in both request-reply from the main flow) received a message to subscribe from one "another-flow reply".